# Configuring Substrate on MacOS

Tags: macos, substrate

Doing a Substrate tutorial for the first time and not able to find an answer elsewhere on the web - getting this error when I try to load Substrate framework:

```
$ curl https://getsubstrate.io -sSf | bash -s -- --fast

Mac OS (Darwin) detected.
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password).
Need sudo access on macOS (e.g. the user patrickburns needs to be an Administrator)!
```

changed to **root** user in sys preferences and tried again:

```
$ curl https://getsubstrate.io -sSf | bash -s -- --fast
Mac OS (Darwin) detected.
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password).
Don't run this as root!
```

Any thoughts on the best way to get permission from macOS to execute the request are most appreciated.

Comment: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks. I reinstalled Rust and then tried this:   

patrickburns@Patricks-MacBook-Air-2 ~ % cd substrate-node-template/
patrickburns@Patricks-MacBook-Air-2 substrate-node-template % git checkout -b my-first-substrate-chain
fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/my-first-substrate-chain': Unable to create '/Users/patrickburns/substrate-node-template/.git/refs/heads/my-first-substrate-chain.lock': Permission denied
patrickburns@Patricks-MacBook-Air-2 substrate-node-template %     

which seems like a similar access issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try running the lines of the script itself.

By looking at: https://getsubstrate.io

```
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright 2015-2020 Parity Technologies (UK) Ltd.

if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "linux-gnu" ]]; then
    set -e
    if [[ $(whoami) == "root" ]]; then
        MAKE_ME_ROOT=
    else
        MAKE_ME_ROOT=sudo
    fi

    if [ -f /etc/redhat-release ]; then
        echo "Redhat Linux detected."
        echo "This OS is not supported with this script at present. Sorry."
        echo "Please refer to https://github.com/paritytech/substrate for setup information."
        exit 1
    elif [ -f /etc/SuSE-release ]; then
        echo "Suse Linux detected."
        echo "This OS is not supported with this script at present. Sorry."
        echo "Please refer to https://github.com/paritytech/substrate for setup information."
        exit 1
    elif [ -f /etc/arch-release ]; then
        echo "Arch Linux detected."
        $MAKE_ME_ROOT pacman -Syu --needed --noconfirm cmake gcc openssl-1.0 pkgconf git clang
        export OPENSSL_LIB_DIR="/usr/lib/openssl-1.0";
        export OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR="/usr/include/openssl-1.0"
    elif [ -f /etc/mandrake-release ]; then
        echo "Mandrake Linux detected."
        echo "This OS is not supported with this script at present. Sorry."
        echo "Please refer to https://github.com/paritytech/substrate for setup information."
        exit 1
    elif [ -f /etc/debian_version ]; then
        echo "Ubuntu/Debian Linux detected."
        $MAKE_ME_ROOT apt update
        $MAKE_ME_ROOT apt install -y cmake pkg-config libssl-dev git gcc build-essential git clang libclang-dev
    else
        echo "Unknown Linux distribution."
        echo "This OS is not supported with this script at present. Sorry."
        echo "Please refer to https://github.com/paritytech/substrate for setup information."
        exit 1
    fi
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
    set -e
    echo "Mac OS (Darwin) detected."

    if ! which brew >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
    fi

    brew update
    brew install openssl cmake llvm
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "freebsd"* ]]; then
    echo "FreeBSD detected."
    echo "This OS is not supported with this script at present. Sorry."
    echo "Please refer to https://github.com/paritytech/substrate for setup information."
    exit 1
else
    echo "Unknown operating system."
    echo "This OS is not supported with this script at present. Sorry."
    echo "Please refer to https://github.com/paritytech/substrate for setup information."
    exit 1
fi

if ! which rustup >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
    source ~/.cargo/env
    rustup default stable
else
    rustup update
    rustup default stable
fi

rustup update nightly
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly

if [[ "$1" == "--fast" ]]; then
    echo "Skipped cargo install of 'substrate' and 'subkey'"
    echo "You can install manually by cloning the https://github.com/paritytech/substrate repo,"
    echo "and using cargo to install 'substrate' and 'subkey' from the repo path."
else 
    g=$(mktemp -d)
    git clone https://github.com/paritytech/substrate "$g"
    pushd "$g"
    cargo install --force --path ./bin/node/cli #substrate
    cargo install --force --path ./bin/utils/subkey subkey
    popd
fi

echo "Run source ~/.cargo/env now to update environment"
```

For MacOS specifically:

```
brew update
brew install openssl cmake llvm

curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
source ~/.cargo/env
rustup default stable

rustup update nightly
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly
```